# Where can I find the IP address or CIDR notation of my Elastic Beanstalk app?

Tags: amazon-web-services, ip, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

My web application is deployed on AWS Elastic Beanstalk and is supposed to access a mongodb database deployed on mongodb Atlas.

In order to make database queries possible, I have to whitelist the IP addresses of the servers accessing the database:

[image]

The problem is that I can find nowhere the IP address of my app.

Where can I find the IP address of my app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot control the public IP addresses of your Elastic Beanstalk instances so you cannot whitelist them with your hosted MongoDB provider.

Your best option is probably to use NAT for egress and associate static IP(s) (Elastic IP) with your NAT instance(s). Here's an [example](https://medium.com/@obezuk/how-to-use-elastic-beanstalk-with-an-ip-whitelisted-api-69a6f8b5f844).